# return only one user while checking two different tables for user name

Tags: mysql

I have two table as following:

`Suppliers:
supplier_id, supplier_pw
      123456       zzzzz
      647890       yyyyy`

`Customers:
customer_id, customer_pw
      00000        zzzzz
      11111        yyyyy`

I've set id for both table as unique and primary key.
After I run the following query:

$username = 123456, $password = zzzzzz.

`SELECT * FROM suppliers, customers WHERE (suppliers.supplier_id = '$username' AND suppliers.supplier_pw = '$password') OR (customers.customer_id = '$username' AND customers.customer_pw = '$password'`

It returns result from suppliers where id = 123456 also the one from customers where password = zzzzzz.
But I would like to let it returns only the one that match both id and password.
Where should I change in my query?

Update tables structure:

suppliers:

supplier_id(PK, unique), supplier_pw, supplier_lastname, supplier_firstname, supplier_email(unique), supplier_phone, company_name(unique), company_address, company_city, company_state, company_zip

customers:

customer_id(PK, unique), customer_pw, customer_lastname, customer_firstname, customer_email(unique), customer_phone, customer_address, customer_city, cusomter_state, customer_zip

Comment: If you want to select data matching with both username and password input and they need to be from both tables if match happens then you can use `union all` but need to make sure that the `select` should have same number of columns in both queries and preferably same name, Provide the complete table structure and desired columns.

Comment: I've update the complete table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select data matching with both username and password input and they need to be from both tables if match happens then you can use `union all` as

```
select 
supplier_id as id,
supplier_lastname as lastname,
supplier_firstname as firstname,
supplier_email as email ,
supplier_phone as phone,
'Supplier' as entity_name
from suppliers 
where suppliers.supplier_id = '$username' AND suppliers.supplier_pw = '$password'
union all
select
customer_id as id,
customer_lastname as lastname,
customer_firstname as firstname,
customer_email as email,
customer_phone as phone,
'Customer' as entity_name 
customers.customer_id = '$username' AND customers.customer_pw = '$password'
```

Note that I have selected few columns from both table and added the alias you can add more if you want but make sure both queries have same number of selection and then added one extra column called `entity_name` to tell you from which table the row is coming in case you have matched data from both tables.